# Для чего используется Mock.Setup().Verifiable()?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, moq

Не могу разобраться для чего используется `Mock.Verifiable()`, если я правильно понимаю, такой код:

```
var mockContainer = new Mock<CloudBlobContainer>(MockBehavior.Strict, StorageUri);
mockContainer.Setup(c => c.GetBlockBlobReference(It.IsAny<string>()))
             .Returns(mockBlobItem.Object);
// ...
mockContainer.Verify(c => c.GetBlockBlobReference(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.AtLeastOnce);
```

Будет эквивалентен такому:

```
var mockContainer = new Mock<CloudBlobContainer>(MockBehavior.Strict, StorageUri);
mockContainer.Setup(c => c.GetBlockBlobReference(It.IsAny<string>()))
             .Returns(mockBlobItem.Object)
             .Verifiable();
// ...
mockContainer.Verify();
```

Есть ещё третий вариант:

```
var mockContainer = new Mock<CloudBlobContainer>(MockBehavior.Strict, StorageUri);
mockContainer.Setup(c => c.GetBlockBlobReference(It.IsAny<string>()))
             .Returns(mockBlobItem.Object);
// ...
mockContainer.Verify();
```

Изучил множество примеров, так вот там используются, как правило, второй или третий варианты. А ещё есть `.VerifyAll()`.

1. Как правильно и почему?
2. Какие есть особенности и подводные камни?
3. Как эти варианты зявисят от моделей поведения **Strict** и **Loose**?

---

Не смог найти документацию к **Moq** (*[кроме вот этой неполноценной](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq/Moq/Moq)*), она вообще есть?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да Вы всё верно поняли.

Насколько можно судить из [статьи](http://derpturkey.com/validate-mock-arguments-with-moq/) этот метод может быть использован для проверки вызова ранее вызова метода определённого в Setup.

```
var thing = new Thing() { Id = 1 };  
var mockMapper = new Mock<IThingMapper>();  
mockMapper.Setup(p => p.Save(thing)).Verifiable();

// do stuff

mockMapper.Verify();
```

Кроме того [согласно англоязычного ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1728496/3218447) желательно не использовать этот подход т.к. он явно противоречит паттерну [AAA](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert). Противоречие заключается в том, что подготовка данных для тестирования (Arrange) и описание того, что должно быть проверено (Assert) происходит в методе **Setup**.

Сами же мейнтейнеры проекта озвучивают ещё рад случаев почему не стоит продолжать [развивать такое АПИ](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/373#issuecomment-335787647)

Тем не менее этот подход может быть оправдан к примеру необходимостью избежать дублитрования кода.

Единственный случай, когда такой подход нельзя будет использовать это при необходимости проверить **количество** вызовов. В этом случае Вы можете использовать только метод **Verify** с полным описание ожидаемого вызова:

```
mock.Verify(c => c.Method(It.Is<string>(x => x == "x")), Times.Once);
```

По поводу использования **Verify** без параметров. Он будет проверять только методы которые Вы в сетапе отметили при помощи метода **Verifiable**:

```
var mockContainer = new Mock<CloudBlobContainer>(MockBehavior.Strict, StorageUri);
mockContainer.Setup(c => c.GetBlockBlobReference(It.IsAny<string>()))
         .Returns(mockBlobItem.Object)
         .Verifiable();
// ...
mockContainer.Verify();
```

Если же вы хотите проверить был ли вызван метод который не был отмечем как **Verifiable**, можно использовать метод **VerifyAll**:

```
var mockContainer = new Mock<CloudBlobContainer>(MockBehavior.Strict, StorageUri);
mockContainer.Setup(c => c.GetBlockBlobReference(It.IsAny<string>()))
         .Returns(mockBlobItem.Object);
// ...
// Verify - не будет проверять в этом случае 
// т.к. Вы не получите ошибку даже если метод не был вызван ни разу
// для такого случая можно сделать так
mockContainer.VerifyAll();
```

Но лично я бы не использовал **VerifyAll** хотя-бы потому, что он ну уж совсем не очевиден.

---

Разработка ведётся на гитхабе и кроме [детальной документации](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq) на которую вы сослались есть [быстрый старт](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) и [примеры использования](https://github.com/moq/moq4/tree/master/Samples).

Comment: Это всё я читал. Можете пояснить разницу в использовании/неиспользовании *Verifiable*? Можете пояснить, чем именно этот подход нарушает принцип *ААА*?

Comment: В случае использования метода **Verifiable()**, вы можете сделать проверку всех заранее определённых в методе **Setup()** вызовов метода и затем при вызове **Verify()** проверить были ли вызваны эти методы.

Паттерн ААА подразумевает явную проверку вызовов. Фактически в секции Assert Вам необходимо явно вызвать метод **Verify** с ожидаемыми параметрами (как вы это делали в _Setup_-е) и ожидаемым количством вызвов.

Comment: в чём разница между вторым и третьим вариантами в вопросе? как используется `VerifyAll()`? быстрый старт даёт весьма поверхностное представление и заставляет "додумывать" многое, что не есть правильно

Comment: @Anatol пробежавшись по коду: третий вариант не будет проверять был ли вызван метод или нет. 
Отличие в методах Verify (без параметров) и VerifyAll (открываю ящик пандоры) в том что последний проверяет были ли вызваны все засетапленные методы хотя-бы один раз. Т.е. VerifyAll можно использовать в третьем кейсе. Вечером проверю "в работе" и поправлю ответ.
PS: Спасибо за интересный вопрос и неподдельный интеерс. Самому интересно.
Вечером дополню ответ.